# Debug Console not working in intelliJ trial version

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ trial version.
We used to relay on Debug console in Eclipse

[image: Eclipse Display Window].

But the same feature is not seem to be present with the IntelliJ 2018.1
Can anybody please suggest what needs to be done

Comment: Do you mean the console where the logs are printed?

Comment: No Karthikeyan,there is a debug terminal available in eclipse where we can write our adhoc codes while debugging.This shall help us in conditions such us,we need to debug the nth element in a for loop or write a piece of code to ease the debug.

Comment: Could you please add the screenshot of that window?

Comment: I have attached the screenshot in the question now

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Evaluate Expression" to run code fragments in a Debug session. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> on Windows/*nix or <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> on a macOs.

The window looks like the below image.

[image]

Any Log or SysOuts will be printed on the Console in the Debug window.

Ref: [Evaluate arbitrary expressions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/examining-suspended-program.html?keymap=secondary_macos#evaluate-arbitrary)